# Cannot Access Registry After Calling GetSubkeyNames()?

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

I thought this was a security issue but after several tries, I am not sure anymore.

I am trying to read subkey names, then read values from the subkeys but I get an 'Requested Registry Access not Allowed', yet the app is running as administrator. Below is my code:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}");
//string[] names = key.GetSubKeyNames(); //causes error at key.OpenSubkey below
string[] names = new[] {"0000", "0001", "0002"};
foreach (string name in names)
{
    string fname =key.OpenSubKey(name).GetValue("FriendlyName").ToString();
    string port =key.OpenSubKey(name).GetValue("AttachedTo").ToString();
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] {name, fname, port}));
}
```

What could be causing this? I tried closing the key but that only adds another trying to access closed key error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as strange as it may sound, it appears this issue happens only when I compile it for *Any Platform*. Changing the project platform target to **x86** solved the problem.

Also, it appeared I didn't even need to have administrative access to start with.